# what does regularization mean in xgboost (tree)

Tags: r, regularization, boosting

In xgboost (`xgbtree`), `gamma` is the tunning parameter to control the regularization. I understand what regularization means in `xgblinear` and logistic regression, but in the context of tree-based methods, I'm not sure how regularization works.

Can someone explain how regularization works in `xgbtree`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In tree-based methods regularization is usually understood as defining a minimum gain so which another split happens:

> Minimum loss reduction required to make a further partition on a leaf
>   node of the tree. The larger gamma is, the more conservative the
>   algorithm will be.

Source: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html

This minimum gain can usually be set for anything between $(0,\infty)$.

[Here's](https://medium.com/data-design/xgboost-hi-im-gamma-what-can-i-do-for-you-and-the-tuning-of-regularization-a42ea17e6ab6) a somewhat good article on how to tune regularization on XGBoost.